# Empty plot when using for loop

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to use a `for` loop to plot a function. The code is

```
y = 0;
for k = 0:0.1:2
    y = y + k;
    plot(k, y);
    hold on;
end
```

However, by running the code, the plot window is empty! How can I fix that in order to see a line on a 2D area?

Comment: `plot(k,y,'0')` doesn't connect the points. I want to see a line. In other words, a continues line connecting the points.

Comment: output `k` for every loop, you will see it is represented as single output values. What you want is a range as `k`, and several values for `y`. You could do this with `k=1:10` and `y=[1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3];` and `plot(k,y)`;

Comment: Yes I know that. However, I want to use the `for` loop.

Comment: If you want to plot a line, you need to specify the x-coordinate range and the y coordinate range. Importantly these vectors need to be of same length. Since you mentioned you do not want to plot points, you need to change your variable `k` to be a range within the loop then. If this range should be dynamic, i.e. change within the loop, that would be a different question... it boils down to 'what do you actually want to do?'

Comment: Using a loop is an over-kill here. Just plot it without the loop

Comment: @SardarUsama, I could be wrong, but the for-loop could be simplified for our sake. At least I gave OP the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @Nicky That's too much to assume. Even if that's true then the original post is not an MCVE. You should ask for clarification from the OP about your doubts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab automatically plots the linear interpolation between the points that are given to the `plot` function. Thus as you only give a single point, no interpolation can happen.

What you can do is to save the old `y` value and the old `x` value to ask Matlab to plot a linear interpolation between these two points. e.g.

```
yold = 0; %Init
kold=0; %Init
for k = 0:0.1:2
    y = yold + k; %New y value
    plot([kold,k], [yold,y]); %Plot a linear interpolation
    kold = k; %Save the new values as old
    yold = y; %Same
    hold on;
end
```

**EDIT/NOTE:**

When adding new plots to the same window, MATLAB automatically changes color, thus the above will give you a rainbow, which is nice, but in case you want to keep it professional, you can add a color to the plot command, e.g.

```
plot([kold,k], [yold,y],'blue');
```

Comment: I think this solution is unwise, sorry to be blunt about it. I don't see why you wouldn't get the data first, then simply plot it.

Comment: I do not see why it is unwise. I would have done the same as you and obtained the data first, but some people like to plot the progress, e.g. if the body of the for-loop takes a long time.

Comment: I have troubles picturing matlab taking a long time to plot a single line, especially in the context of OP's question. Here's some scenarios I can picture better, but this solution would be un-elegant:
1) you want to debug raw data in a cumbersome way 
2) you just want to see how it is drawn slowly for the sake of seeing it be plotted slowly (of which could be gained little to no knowledge)
3) you are actualy interested in a movie of 'the plot being drawn' in way that you have troubles saving that data afterwards.